# How easy or difficult it is to exploit older SSL/TLS protocols?

Tags: tls, exploit, attacks, heartbleed

Detection of outdated TLS/SSL protocols are one of the most common findings I have seen in many vulnerability scans and penetration testing reports. It is reported as a serious vulnerability too. Every time I see this, I wonder how easy or difficult it is to exploit an old TLS/SSL protocol? The way the older TLS1.0/1.1 vulnerabilities are generally talked about, it sounds like a regular joe hacker can exploit all the programs employing TLS1.0/1.1 using only his or her laptop - that obviously is not the case, or is it? Except for the Heartbleed vulnerability, is an MITM always a pre-requisite to exploit old TLS/SSL protocols? Are these vulnerabilities exploitable only by nation state level attackers?

This is not a question about how to attack SSL3/TLS1.0 or TLS1.1, but a question about difficulty level and resources needed to exploit the older TLS/SSL protocols.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/243483/are-any-tls-attacks-practical-for-an-attacker-who-can-only-observe-traffic

Comment: You've only mentioned HEARTBLEED. Are you aware of the other attacks?

Comment: @schroeder, not intimately familiar, but like many on the forum I have read about POODLE, CROWN, BREACH.. similar well-known vulnerabilities. Thank you for the link to that old post.

Comment: and have you read how to exploit those vulnerabilities?

Comment: Most SSL "vulnerabilities" require expensive hardware and a ton of time, and they don't guarantee you'll be able to decrypt the traffic in real time. Breaking the MD5 hash algo is relatively easy nowadays, not so much for already deprecated SHA1.

Comment: Most notorious attacks on SSL/TLS including the ones mentioned above require a MITM capable of tampering with the packets between the client and the server.  However, this in itself is not a high bar - for example, if you are on a shared wifi network, another user on the network may be able to MITM your connection by way of ARP spoofing.  See https://witestlab.poly.edu/blog/conduct-a-simple-man-in-the-middle-attack-on-a-wifi-hotspot/ for more info.